# svm can it give equation like linear regression model

Tags: r, svm, linear-regression

I am trying to classify respondents into 5 Clusters, using survey details.

Using Multi-Nomial Linear Regression I am getting correction classification of 56%. When I was using SVM(RBM Kernel v-svm) I am able to get classification of 61%(Increased from 56%).

For Multi-Nomial I used R(Rattle) - The Output has equation for all clusters. So I Can implement the model in excel or any other software.

But when I was running SVM(R - Rattle & Python - Orange) both of them didn't give any equation. While I liked the classification results of SVM, but without any equation/s I can't use it. As our client want the model in excel only.

Below are my queries.

1. Is there any way SVM can generate Equations like a linear regression/classification model.
2. I tried SVM, NN, RF all of them didn't generate any equation. Is there any other model which give results on par with SVM/RF and can be implemented in excel.

Comment: Some hints on svm in excel can be found here: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/58272/how-can-one-set-up-a-linear-support-vector-machine-in-excel

Comment: It is preferred if you can post separate questions instead of combining your questions into one. That way, it helps the people answering your question and also others hunting for at least one of your questions.

Answer (score 2):

You can always extract the exact equation from any model, but this won't be so "nice" as in case of linear regression (which is quite obvious - "nice" equations are simple equations, simple equations are generally weak models).

In case of RBF SVM you can extract equation in functional form, so

```
svm(x) = sgn( SUM_i alpha_i K(x_i,x) + b )
```

where `x_i` are support vectors (subset of training examples, which you can "write down") and K(x,y) is a RBF kernel:

```
K(x,y) = e^(-gamma||x-y||^2)
```

where gamma is a parameter used in your code

So the whole equation becomes

```
svm(x) = sgn( alpha_1 e^(-gamma||x_1-x||^2) + alpha_2 e^(-gamma||x_2-x||^2) + ... + alpha_n e^(-gamma||x_n-x||^2)  + b)
```